# How to design for devices that are both mouse and touch enabled?

Tags: responsive-design, touch, mouseevent, device

Just wondering if there are specific libraries or standards that help developers manage the interactions for devices that are both mouse and touch enabled (e.g. netbooks, laptops). I have been doing some testing of websites on such devices and the user experience is not ideal because the browser seems to just make a choice about the device being a desktop machine that you use with a mouse or a touch device that doesn't have mouse input at certain points and it would be great to have better control over this without rewriting a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

For my code, I add events for mouse and touch, and in the event handler pass on the coords to a custom function that they both share.

For example:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseStart, false);

window.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);

function mouseStart(e) {
  handleStart(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

function touchStart(e) {
  handleStart(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);
}

function handleStart(x, y) {
  // Both touch and mouse events end up here and provide their coords
}
```

That way, one piece of code handles mobile and desktop equally.

In general, I try to leave comments or write a note down somewhere whenever I implement something that is not compatible with all devices so I can come back to it later.

Comment: +1 Sort of, can you provide a bit more detail because I am not really a developer? Even if it is just some reference?